# Running emacs client: how do you know if the init files had errors loading

Tags: init-file, emacsclient, prelude, error-handling, emacs-daemon

I use emacs 25, in nw mode, with "alias emacs='emacsclient -nw'"
When I add something to my personal.el, I do

```
brew services restart emacs
```

My issue is, if I make a big blunder inside my personal.el file,
brew restart emacs daemon and start emacs client, there's no indication
that something has gone very wrong.

How do other folks do this?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest that if you're starting an emacs daemon as a service, you should be logging any errors as well, and ideally having that reported on in a way you'll notice.

You could also try setting a variable at the very end of your init file to indicate "yep, we got this far", and then writing some elisp to check on that.